# Generating pure javascript/css files using JSF 1.2/Facelets

Tags: javascript, jsf, facelets

I need to generate a pure JavaScript file or pure css file dynamically using JSF 1.2/Facelets.
When I mean 'pure' I mean without any markup like xml, html open/close tags.

Is this possible? If so what settings do I need to use for the facelets output mechanism.

To give you a bit of history, I am trying to use the TinyMCE editor in my jsf application and to configure the list of images, it is supplied with a file name. The file is read and parsed on the client side and need to be just javascript and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory serves, JSF 1.2 Facelets mandate producing XHTML. I imagine it is technically possible to do what you want even if you might have to resort to transforming the resultant XML (e.g. using XSLT) in a servlet `Filter`.

It would be significantly easier to do using a JSP in the same application:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/javascript; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                                                 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<f:view>
   var foo = '<h:outputText value="#{bar.baz}" escape="false" />';
</f:view>
```